# Give user Full Control to all Service Applications in a farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How to give a user Full Control to all Service Applications in a SharePoint farm?

Service applications like manage metadata service,search service etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration navigate to Manage Service Applications in the section Application Management or use the direct URL http://CentralAdminURL:port/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx

Select the row of the service application and click "Administrators" which will give users access to the application:

> Specify the users who have rights to manage this service application.
>   These users will be given access to the Central Administration site
>   and will be able to manage settings related to this service
>   application. Members of the Farm Administrators group always have
>   rights to manage all service applications.

I wouldn't recommend to add users to the Farm Administrators group, just the service applications they are supposed to manage.

[image]